# CMake can't find external library

Tags: c++, cmake, libusb-1.0

I am trying to build an application that uses the LibUSB library.

In a previous question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995936/how-to-link-a-third-party-library-libusb-in-cmake/) I was told to use `find_path` and `find_library` to make CMake search for the headers and binaries. However even after manually looking up the library's installation locations with `dnf` and specifying them as `PATHS` or `HINTS` I always still get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lUSB
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Below is the relevent cmakelists.txt, my import line in main.cpp is `#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>`

```
add_executable(project main.cpp)
find_path(LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES libusb.h
  PATHS "/usr/include/"
  PATH_SUFFIXES "include" "libusb")
find_library(LIBUSB_LIBRARY
  NAMES USB
  HINTS "/usr/lib/" "/usr/lib64/" "/usr/include/"
  PATH_SUFFIXES "lib" "lib32" "lib64")

target_include_directories(project PRIVATE "/usr/lib/" "/usr/lib64/")
target_link_libraries(project USB)
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong in this kludge of hacks, but could someone tell me what?

Comment: Shouldn't you *use* `${LIBUSB_LIBRARY}` somewhere?

Comment: If you did not understand my answer, please help improve it by comments to the answer.

Comment: @usr1234567 I understood your answer but thought I was now asking a different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown Back in the original question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35033932/5837486), all of the finding and including functions can be replaced simply with:

`target_link_libraries(project_name <other_dependencies> usb-1.0)`,

in the file where the build target is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the result of your find operations anywhere. You tell CMake to find the headers and store the found paths in `LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR`, and to find the library and store its location in `LIBUSB_LIBRARY`, and then you go to ignore these and use hardcoded `"/usr/lib/" "/usr/lib64/"` and `USB` instead. Try this:

```
target_include_directories(project PRIVATE ${LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(project ${LIBUSB_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: I tried your solution, however my error changed to: 
`/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/botspotptp.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'libusb_set_debug'
/usr/lib64/libusb-1.0.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` What is a DSO?

Comment: @LordNibbler Have you asked uncle Google? Perhaps you should review a few tutorials on linking "manually," before CMake enters the picture.

Comment: I don't see what manually linking has to do with CMake; besides as any good internet citizen I thoroughly scoured google before posting here. I found a reference to needing pthread, which I found and included using the same method, but that did not resolve or change the issue.

Comment: @LordNibbler I suggested that because a "DSO" (dynamic shared object, IIUC) has nothing to do with CMake. And because you were talking about include directories and headers in the context of unresolved references.