# How to link Argon2 library with cmake in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, shared-libraries, .so

I would like to use the password-hashing function [Argon2](https://github.com/p-h-c/phc-winner-argon2) in my C++ application. But I get a error if I build the application:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libargon2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What I did so far: I downloaded the source in a subfolder of my Qt project folder (thirdparty > Argon2). Called `make` to build the Argon .so and verified with `make test` that everything is ok. The project structure looks like this:

```
testproject > CMakeLists.txt
testproject > application > test > impl > src > Main.cpp
testproject > thirdparty > Argon2 > include > argon2.h
testproject > thirdparty > Argon2 > libargon2.so
```

In my CMakeLists I added Argon include path and TRIED to link against the .so file:

```
find_library(Argon2 NAMES libargon2 PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/Argon2)
# Additional include directories
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}                     
                    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/Argon2/include
target_link_libraries(${COMPONENT_NAME} ${Argon2})
```

But this simple test program will give me the above mentioned error.

```
#include "argon2.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HASHLEN 32
#define SALTLEN 16
#define PWD "password"  

int main(){  

    uint8_t hash1[HASHLEN];

    uint8_t salt[SALTLEN];
    memset( salt, 0x00, SALTLEN );

    uint8_t *pwd = (uint8_t *)strdup(PWD);
    uint32_t pwdlen = strlen((char *)pwd);

    uint32_t t_cost = 2;            // 1-pass computation
    uint32_t m_cost = (1<<16);      // 64 mebibytes memory usage
    uint32_t parallelism = 1;       // number of threads and lanes

    argon2i_hash_raw(t_cost, m_cost, parallelism, pwd, pwdlen, salt, SALTLEN, hash1, HASHLEN);     
}
```

I'm still very new to C++ and CMake, so I don't know if my procedure was correct (obviously not, because it does not work).

1. Is it possible to link only the .so file?
2. Will I have to include the whole directory of the Argon library in my project (like I tried)?
3. What are the necessary steps to tell my linker how to find the library correctly?

**EDIT**

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995936/how-to-link-a-third-party-library-libusb-in-cmake) seems to be similar to mine. But I can't figure out be their answers if the .so file would be sufficient and how to link against a library which is not installed by the package manager of my debian system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Link a third Party Library (LibUSB) in CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995936/how-to-link-a-third-party-library-libusb-in-cmake)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. At least I can't figure out how to solve my problem by the answers in the question you mentioned.

Comment: Well, the question post has been *changed* and it is no more duplicate of one I suggest. Now you link with the library (`target_link_libraries`), and instead of "undefined reference" you get error about inability to find the library. Is this error a *link error* (you failed to *create* executable) or *run error* (you failed to *run* executable)? Looks like the second case, because such error normally arizes when run executables.

Comment: Yes it's an error during runtime. However I was able to link the static library (same folder as .so) with target_link_libraries. But this is not what I intended.

Comment: Probably, your executable lacks of RPATH tuning. See [this wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling) about RPATH and how CMake can handle it. You can always check correctness of RPATH settings using `ldd <binary-file>`. For the future: try to describe situation more precizely. You write `I get a error if I build the application`, and it is normally understood as error you catch during the *build*. But actually this is an error during the *run* of the application.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is to download the repository and run the `make` command inside of it. This should create the static library `libargon2.a`. Then in your CMakeLists.txt add

```
include_directories(libs/argon2/include)
link_directories(libs/argon2)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} argon2)
```

where `libs/argon2` represents the relative path to the downloaded repository.

Answer (score 0):

In my project in `project/` directory I have cloned Argon2 into `project/argon2/` with `CMakeLists.txt`

```
...
target_include_directories(target PUBLIC argon2/include)
target_link_libraries(target argon2)
```

In code I include Argon2 via `#include <argon2.h>` and it works for me.